# is this line in the grails documentation redundant?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

First please go here

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne

If you scroll few lines, you'll see the line

*Finally, it's a good idea to add a unique constraint on one side of the one-to-one relationship:*

The code is

```
class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose:Nose]
    static constraints = {
        nose unique: true
    }
}
```

I took out the changelog of the following two domain definitions without the unique:true

```
class Nose {

    String name
    Cat cat

    static constraints = {
    }
}

class Cat {

    String name
    static hasOne = [nose: Nose]


    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

and the changelog shows that the unique has been added

```
    <changeSet author="S (generated)" id="1452758231706-5">
        <createIndex indexName="cat_id_unique_1452758231629" tableName="nose" unique="true">
            <column name="cat_id"/>
        </createIndex>
    </changeSet>
```

So, although this is not a big deal to have few redundant statements in the docs i wanted to make sure that the unique:true is really not necessary. Specifying hasOne and having a back reference is enough to make the relationship truly one to one. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: with unique you can have a null value also but not with hasOne and a back reference.

Comment: @SandeepPoonia I tested and even with unique constraint, null value is not allowed.